# Why is trace operation involved when calculating gradient and Hessian?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, hessian-matrix

The following passage is from section $11.8.3$ of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/),

> We consider the SDP $$\operatorname{minimize}\quad c^Tx\\
> \text{subject to} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n x_iF_i + G\preceq 0,$$
> with variable $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$, and parameters $F_1,\dots, F_n, G \in\mathbf{S}^p$.
> The associated centering problem, using the log-determinant barrier function, is
> $$\operatorname{minimize}\quad tc^T x − \log \det \left( −\sum_{i=1}^n x_i F_i − G \right).$$
> The Newton step $\Delta x_{nt}$ is found from $H\Delta x_{nt} = −g$, where the Hessian and gradient
> are given by
> $$H_{ij} = \mathbf{tr}(S^{−1}F_iS^{−1}F_j),\quad i, j = 1,\dots, n$$
> $$g_i = tc_i + \mathbf{tr}(S^{−1}F_i),\quad  i = 1,\dots, n,$$
> where $S = −\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_iF_i − G$.

---

From the Matrix Cookbook, I got

$$\frac{\partial\ln\det(S)}{\partial S}=S^{-1}, \qquad \frac{\partial\operatorname{tr}(AS^{-1}B)}{\partial S}=-(S^{-1}BAS^{-1})^T$$

Since all matrices are symmetric in our context,

$$\frac{\partial\operatorname{tr}(S^{-1}F_i)}{\partial S}=-S^{-1}F_iS^{-1}F_j$$

I know that $g_i$ denotes the gradient of log-determinant barrier function w.r.t $x_i$. In terms of size constraints, trace is involved to get a scalar, why do not we use other scalarization operators? I encountered many cases in which trace is invovled when computing derivatives, but I haven't figured out why trace operation is useful in such contexts. I think lots of people would like to know the reason. Any instrucitons will be apppreciated.

Comment: We have a very good framework, and a clear reference, wonderful. However, for the specific need of a potential answerer to focus on the question, it is hard to put the hands on it. We have a lot of notations and objects, that are maybe not so important for the final issue. And the only question "*In terms of size constraints, trace is involved to get a scalar, why do not we use other scalarization operators?*" is hard to be connected with all the given data. Could you please isolate only the needed structure? **The** Hessian is the Hessian of which function? What is ${\bf S} ^p$ exactly?

Comment: @dan_fulea What is the framework or reference? The Hessian is the Hessian of the log-determinant barrier function. $\mathbf{S}^p$ represents $p\times p$ symmetric matrics. I have to quote more to include the needed notations.

Comment: This is not the place to fix notations, please do it in the text of the question. Of course that i had to guess that ${\bf S}^p$ is what is said above, when i saw that this is used... Else i would have to buy the referenced book to have all notations. We still don't know which is the barrier function, and what exactly is the "log-determinant barrier function". Is it so complicated to isolate and write down this function, so that we can focus on the question? Is it the function $$x\to \log \pm\det\left(\sum_i x_i F_i+G\right)\ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\G{{\cal G}}\def\X{{\cal X}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qfq{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Consider the gradient and differential of a scalar-valued function $(\phi)$ of a third-order tensor $(\X)$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{\X_{ijk}} = \G_{ijk} \qfq
     d\phi = \sum_{i,j,k}\;\G_{ijk}\;d\X_{ijk} \\
}$$
Notice that one must sum over **every** component of the independent variable.

The situation is exactly the same when the independent variable is a second-order tensor (i.e. a matrix) $-$ except there's one less index.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{X_{ij}} = G_{ij} \qfq
     d\phi = \sum_{i,j}\;G_{ij}\;dX_{ij} \\
}$$
But notice that the expression on the RHS can be written using the *trace* function
$$\eqalign{
 d\phi = \sum_{i,j}\;G_{ij}\;dX_{ij} \;\doteq\; \trace{G^TdX} \\
}$$
This is the reason that the trace appears so often in matrix calculus.